# Jquery+Ajax: Run a plugin with no page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am using a snowStorm plugin to generate a snow storm effect on my webpage.

I am trying to make it so if they click one button eg "Summer", the snowStorm will stop and if they click another button eg "Winter" the snowStorm will run again.

Now i got this working:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#Winter").click(function(){
 $.getScript("js/snowStorm.js")
 {
 location.reload();
 }
  });

  $("#Summer").click(function(){
   snowStorm.stop()
  });
```

I was wondering if there is a better way of improving this code so it will not reload the entire page to run the snowStorm effect. I was thinking of using AJAX (No page refresh) but im not sure if that will solve the problem here

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing what is `snow.js`?! Just wondering, hasn't this plugin got a `play()` method?.

Comment: Sorry, i meant `snowStorm.js` . And no it hasn't - I used this plugin: http://www.schillmania.com/projects/snowstorm/

Comment: Seems I didn't wait long enough when i used snowStorm.resume() ..extremely stupid of me . Thanks man

Answer (score 4):

There are two methods,
`snowStorm.resume()`
and
`snowStorm.stop()`,
through which you can achieve this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
      $("#Winter").click(function() {
        snowStorm.resume();
      });

      $("#Summer").click(function() {
        snowStorm.stop();
});
```

Comment: This should be posted as a comment, not as an answer.

Comment: Still, that doesn't mean you can post a comment as an answer.

Comment: i changed my answer too. You can check it.

Answer (score 0):

Very weird they didn't build in a proper start method, but I figured it out.

```
$("#Winter").click(function(){
    snowStorm.init()
});

$("#Summer").click(function(){
    snowStorm.stop()
});
```

Comment: And is probably better.... but his answer was only updated later. I think his is more correct FYI

Comment: Surprisingly `init` works better than `resume`. There is no delay for the snow to load